# Google Web Font Loader only loads single font on firefox

Tags: javascript, font-face, google-webfonts

Debugging 2 seperate bugs here but first thing is first. I have specified 2 fonts to be loaded from my server using google font loader, SilkScreen and SilkScreenBold, on firefox SilkScreenBold is loaded for me every time but SilkScreen is not.

http://junk.arandomurl.com/helicopter/test.html

Alternatively if anyone could give me a different surefire way of ensuring a font has loaded then I am all ears

Comment: @I DROPPED the test html does show what it explains

Answer (score 0):

Are you specifying the font anywhere in your CSS? Some browsers including Firefox and Safari don't download a font file until it is actually needed to render text.